# How can you transfer your playlists from one YouTube account to other?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

How can you transfer your playlists from one YouTube account to other YouTube account? I sign under different names in Gmail.

Answer (score 3):

You save it as a new playlist to the second account.

1. Sign in with the account where you want to transfer the playlist;
2. Go to the playlist that you want to transfer;
3. From the playlist bar, click **Options**;
   [image]
4. Click **Save as new playlist**;
   [image]
5. Insert the (new) title of the playlist;
6. Click **Save**.

Now you have the playlist from the first account saved as a playlist of the second account.

Comment: I don't see any Options -where is the playlist bar? What I see is "Play all/Share/Like"

Comment: bte I have the new Video Manager

Comment: @Theta30 At the bottom of the page. Make sure you are on the playlist's page.

Comment: This is great, just one thing. I have a favorite playlist of 1117 videos and want to swap it to a new account.
IT ONLY LETS ME SAVE THE FIRST 79 VIDEOS ONTO THE PLAYLIST!

Comment: the post seems to be obsolete, but I dont know what to do with it

Comment: @Theta30 - leaving a comment is good, as would down-voting if the answer is now wrong or unhelpful.

Comment: @Theta30 Since this solution is obsolete, you can either add a new answer with the current solution or add it to this one by editing it.

Comment: Here's a current solution: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70934/14334