# How to copy YouTube playlist from one account to another

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

The link below provides the old answer to this question. The new YouTube playlist play interface is very different. So, what's the trick now? Tired of searching!

[How can you transfer your playlists from one YouTube account to other?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23532/how-can-you-transfer-your-playlists-from-one-youtube-account-to-other)

Comment: Newest version of this question [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/150762/146176)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy YouTube playlist to your account (ver. 2021)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/150762/copy-youtube-playlist-to-your-account-ver-2021)

Answer (score 36):

The [top answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70934/9617) no longer works, but [this reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/juozzw/how_to_make_a_copy_of_a_playlist/gnlj22m?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) functions as of May 2021.

> You can copy the other person's playlist to the new playlist by taking
> the url of the other person's playlist, swapping out the www for music
> ([www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) to music.youtube.com ) which will give you the
> youtube music version of the playlist. from there you can click on the
> three dots and there will be an option to add all to playlist.

[image]

Comment: This no longer works properly, as of Feb 2022. You can follow these steps, but the new playlist will only show up in YouTube Music, and not YouTube. It seems that new playlists on the two services are no longer shared.

Comment: @DanJones from one of the comments on Reddit "the copy of the playlist has to be unlisted for it to appear in the YouTube app, private playlists don't work"

Comment: Doesn't work any more... the UI has been redone and the 'Shuffle' button is a tiny one at the bottom of the page. There are no longer 'three dots' next to it. There are three dots next to individual songs thogh.

Comment: It worked for me in December 2022.

Comment: Still works (Dec 2023). Don't forget to change the url to _music.youtube.com_

Answer (score 31):

1. Navigate to the URL of the playlist you want to copy.
2. Click on the menu button on the right (3 vertical dots).
3. Select "Add all to..."
4. Either add the videos to an existing playlist or create a new one.

Done! {See Attached Screenshot}

In order to see with the "Add all to..." button you need to append the following to the playlist URL: `&disable_polymer=true`

[image: Steps to save playlist]

Comment: As of 2017 in order to see with the "Add all to..." button you need to append the following to the playlist URL: `&disable_polymer=true`

Comment: No longer works because of the new interface.

Comment: @Hiccup: see jj_'s comment above.

Comment: @jj_ Thank you! Adding  <code> &disable_polymer=true </code> to someone else's playlist still worked just now, when I wanted to add their list into one of my own. :-)

Comment: Your tip saved me hours of work. Thanks a million.

Comment: As of right now, this gives the following error: This functionality is not available right now. Please try again later.

Comment: No, its not working anymore. &disable_polymer=true change nothing, no option "Add all to". I can't understand why Youtube is removing such options, clearly not in favor of the users.

Comment: This doesn't work on the eve' of 2021.  Figures.  #FUGoogle

Answer (score 4):

A pretty fast work around for this in almost as many steps as using the non free 3rd party website, with only a few more clicks than number of videos in the playlist would be:

1. Empty your watch later list
2. On the playlist page, starting with the last video on the bottom of the playlist so they will be in order, add all the videos to "watch later" (there is a little button in the corner of the thumbnails). Be sure to select all of them.
3. Go to  video manager > watch later in the left bar (this doesn't show up in playlist view so open up youtube.com in a new tab).
4. Click the select all box.
5. Click the playlist drop down, then select add to new playlist. Give it a name and a privacy setting, then click create new playlist.
6. To check to see if it worked go to playlists in the left bar and open the one you just created.
7. Go back to your watch later list, select all and click remove to clean up.
8. Sit back and enjoy your watching your playlist on your TV with XBMC :)

Comment: Youtube seems to have removed links to the watch later playlist from the playlist manager, but it is still accessible here: https://www.youtube.com/feed/watch_later

Comment: this suggestion is totally useless in 2022

Answer (score 2):

The only suggestion I've seen thus far is to go to the playlist, add all the items to your watch later list, then select them all and select to add them all to a new playlist. It's hackish and silly. I wanted to execute some javascript via an in browser editor to add each video to the watch later list in one fell swoop. Unfortunately jQuery doesn't seem to be loaded and I don't feel like writing the straight javascript. Hopefully someone will write some add ons for browsers to do just that. Or possibly go through the YouTube API.

Answer (score 0):

**Liking a playlist will add it to the “playlists” section in the vertical menu bar on the left**

I just found out another alternative for grabbing someone’s playlist by accident (though the playlist appears in your channel, you don’t actually copy their playlist to your own collection of playlists).

I was trying to delete playlists on the desktop, but I noticed some extra playlists there were appearing in my tablet. These playlists were in the vertical menu bar on the left, and I couldn’t delete these particular playlists.

Going back on the desktop, I didn’t see these playlists when I clicked on “playlists” on the top, which is to the right of your name.

I found out that they weren’t actually my playlists. I initially didn’t know why someone else’s playlist were showing up in my list of playlists, but then I noticed that I had liked their playlist.

Liking a playlist will add it to the “playlists” section in the vertical menu bar on the left (not the top). I suppose that the “playlists” on the left are your playlists, as well as other people's playlists that you have liked.