# How to copy all videos from someone's YouTube playlist (YouTube ver. 2017)

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

For the old YouTube site I used to do it this way: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70934/171425 . So I just could open someone's playlist and save it - add all videos to my new or existing playlist.

But I cannot figure out how to do it with newest YouTube site, is it even possible now?

New YouTube playlist page looks like this:

[image: New YouTube playlist page]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

YouTube's new interface named "Polymer" disables the playlist duplicating/editing functionality of another channel's playlist.

A workaround (for the time being) is to temporarily disable the new interface. To do so, navigate to the desired playlist's page (as shown in the OP's screenshot) and add either "?disable_polymer=1" or "&disable_polymer=1" onto the end of the URL.

Example: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS&disable_polymer=1

After you enter the new page, click the three dots at the top-right corner, and add all of the videos to a new playlist. You can now go to your new playlist and edit it however you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much. It still works (20.09.2019). But i don't get it, why Youtube doesn't fix this.

Anyway Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This still works 09.10.2020 youtube is a silly place.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the the 3 dot menu and then click on RESTORE CLASSIC YOUTUBE. Then it should appear is it was the old and then you can repeat the process that you did before.

Comment: I also noticed this https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39686/how-to-copy-youtube-playlist-from-one-account-to-another/70934#comment94001_70934 But it's not good, either (switching to old version temporary), why is it not available for new version of the site? old version will be not available at some point, Youtube site content designers doing some wrong stuff...

Comment: @user924 I can't see a `RESTORE CLASSIC YOUTUBE` on the 3 dot menu. Can you please add a screenshot to your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use diskyt.com.

Documentation how to copy from YT: [Copy from YT](https://github.com/mp31415/DiskYT/blob/master/docs/CopyFromYouTubeToDiskYT.md)
Documentation how to copy to YT: [Copy to YT](https://github.com/mp31415/DiskYT/blob/master/docs/CopyToYouTube.md)

There is one catch. To allow copying back to YT you need to grant temporary access to your YT channel to diskyt.com. It may be safer to use some intermediate/throw away YT channel first if you are paranoid enough.

Disclaimer: I work on diskyt.com.