# Copy YouTube playlist to your account (ver. 2021)

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I want to copy the videos from a YouTube playlist into a playlist on my own account, so that I can modify the playlist to exclude a couple videos and include others - is this possible, and if so, how?

[Old question with defunct answers that don't
work with the new YouTube interface](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39686/how-to-copy-youtube-playlist-from-one-account-to-another)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way I have found to do it so far is from YouTube Music, which means that it only works with playlists that are available as YouTube Music playlists. I've included the steps in list form, with images afterwards.

- Find the playlist on YouTube
- Enter the playlist and locate the playlist title
- Click on the title to enter the list view
- Double-click on the address bar: replace `www` with `music` (NOTE: it is not sufficient to simply add `music` before `youtube`; you must remove the `www`.
- Click on the three dots next to "Add to Library" and click on "Add to Playlist."  If you want to copy it to a blank playlist, click "Create new playlist."

---

### With pictures to help follow

- #### Find the playlist on YouTube

[image: Find playlist]

- #### Enter the playlist and locate the playlist title

[image: Playlist title]

- #### Click on the title to enter the list view

[image: List view]

- #### Double-click on the address bar: replace `www` with `music` (NOTE: it is not sufficient to simply add `music` before `youtube`; you must remove the `www`

[image: Address bar]

- #### Click on the three dots next to "Add to Library" and click on "Add to Playlist" (appologies for french text)

[image: Three dots]

---

All that being said, it's not the optimal solution, and I'd love it if someone would share a method that would work for all YouTube playlists with the new YouTube interface.

Answer (score 0):

I found that most solutions just linked the other playlist, didn't actually copy or move it.  I needed to move from one to another, or at least copy without any links, so it was disconnected from original.  Found this site that allowed me to enter both the YouTube accounts, then it copied them in their entirety, intact, for free.  but Google imposed a 10 playlist per day creation limit, I had to do i tin 2 sessions.  definitely WAY easier than 6 other convoluted and labor intensive ways I tried.

https://www.tunemymusic.com/YouTube-to-File.php#step5

(I have no affiliation, this worked as of YouTube's current version as of 2/25/23)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024, I fail to see any "Select All" button on the Youtube Playlists pages. To work around this, there are some chrome extensions which allow multiselecting videos from youtube playlists.

- Free: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/multiselect-for-youtube/gpgbiinpmelaihndlegbgfkmnpofgfei
- Paid: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/pockettube-youtube-playli/bplnofkhjdphoihfkfcddikgmecfehdd

With one of these, you can select all the videos from the playlist you want and add them to a new or existing playlist.

Answer (score -1):

YouTube seems to have fixed this: under the 3-dots menu button, there's now a collaborate function, leading to a menu where collaboration can be switched on, you'll also see a playlist URL that can be copied.

This URL will open in other YouTube accounts. You'll see a '**add to** [current account]' text, and a **Continue** button. If you press it, the playlist will become visible in the current account. It seems playlists need to be set to Unlisted or Public. If set to Private, you'll get a 'playlist does not exist' in the other account.