# How to copy YouTube playlist from one account to another?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

NOTE: This is a duplicate of this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39686/how-to-copy-youtube-playlist-from-one-account-to-another) and I made it because my account is new I couldn't neither comment nor answer the question so I decided to ask it and answer it myself. If you're a mod/admin try moving my answer to the previous question if you can.

Comment: @serenesat No, that's why I re-asked it just so I can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution!

1. Sign up here https://soundiiz.com/register/
2. Go to https://soundiiz.com/webapp/playlists
3. Click "import playlist" at the top right corner
4. Choose "from web url"
5. Post your desired playlist URL and voila!